# chicken scheme -- csc cannot locate 'chicken.foreign.import.so'

Tags: scheme, chicken-scheme

I'm trying to write a simple program in Chicken Scheme with some inline C on OS X where Chicken has been installed with homebrew.

```
;; add1.ss

(import foreign)

(define add-1
  (foreign-lambda* long ((unsigned-long x))
                   "
                   long n = 1
                   C_return(n + x);))

(print (add-1 (read)))
```

The `foreign` library I am interested in definitely exists.

```
find /usr/local | grep chicken | grep foreign | grep lib
/usr/local//Cellar/chicken/5.0.0/lib/chicken/9/chicken.foreign.import.so
```

But, compiling my program via `csc add1.ss` with no flags in the `CSC_OPTIONS` environment variables produces:

```
$ csc add1.ss
Syntax error (import): cannot import from undefined module

        foreign

        Expansion history:

        <syntax>          (##core#begin (import foreign))
        <syntax>          (import foreign)      <--

Error:shell command terminated with non-zero exit status 17920:
'/usr/local/Cellar/chicken/bin/5.0.0/bin/chicken' 'add1.ss' -output-file 'add1.c'
```

So, this error message makes a lot of sense, running

```
$ chicken add1.ss -output-file add1.c
```

produces the same failure. The only command line option seemingly related to path management in the chicken manpage is `-include-path`. I tried the following incantations, and all of them produced the same error

```
$ chicken add1.ss -output-file add1.c -include-path /usr/local/Cellar/chicken/5.0.0/lib/chicken/9/chicken.foreign.import.so
$ chicken add1.ss -output-file add1.c -include-path /usr/local/Cellar/chicken/5.0.0/lib/chicken/9
$ chicken add1.ss -output-file add1.c -include-path /usr/local/Cellar/chicken/5.0.0/lib/chicken
$ chicken add1.ss -output-file add1.c -include-path /usr/local/Cellar/chicken/5.0.0/lib
$ chicken add1.ss -output-file add1.c -include-path /usr/local/Cellar/chicken/5.0.0
```

I also tried passing the `chicken.foreign.import.so` as an additional "file to be compiled" but to no avail:

```
$ chicken add1.ss -output-file add1.c /usr/local/Cellar/chicken/5.0.0/lib/chicken/9/chicken.foreign.import.so
```

which produced the same error message.

What is the right way to direct `chicken` or the compiler driver `csc` to look for Chicken's internal libraries in the directory under `/usr/local/Cellar/chicken/...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foreign` is the old name of that module, from CHICKEN 4.  You've installed CHICKEN 5, where we have completely refactored all modules. This particular one has simply been renamed for consistency with the other ones. In CHICKEN 5, this module is called [(chicken foreign)](http://wiki.call-cc.org/man/5/Module%20(chicken%20foreign))

So you would need to do

```
(import (chicken foreign))
```

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly what I did wrong. If `chicken.foreign.import.so` had been installed in a strange location due to carelessness, how would you tell `csc`/`chicken` where to look for it?

Comment: You can use the `CHICKEN_REPOSITORY_PATH` environment variable or the [repository-path](https://wiki.call-cc.org/man/5/Module%20(chicken%20platform)#repository-path) run-time parameter to define where it searches your system for dynamic extensions. But I wouldn't recommend this unless you really know what you're doing :)

Comment: By the way, if you'd like more direct support I can recommend visiting `#chicken` on [freenode](https://freenode.net/). There are many more CHICKEN users there than on Stack Overflow. The chicken-users mailing list is a good one too.